# dictionary.app in macOS

Tags: dictionary, macos-sierra

I have created a dictionary to use with macOS Dictionary Application.
I have created an installer (pkg with postinstall script to move the dictionary into ~/Library/Dictionaries.

I am trying to understand if I can activate that dictionary automatically i.e without having to go to Dictionary.app/Preferences and check the box.

Any direction would be very welcome.

Thanks,
Ines